ambiguity: she didn't sing as you said
a. She didn't sing as you said.
b. She didn't sing**,** as you said.
c. She didn't sing as you said she did.
d. She didn't sing**,** as you said she did.
In which case does the sentence mean:

She sang but not in the manner that you said she sang

in which case does it mean:

You said she sang, but she didn't sing at all.

and in which case does it mean:

You said she didn't sing, and that was true. She didn't sing.

Many thanks

Often, speakers like to clarify and add extra words in order to avoid ambiguities 1. She didn't sing as well as you told me. 2. She didn't sing despite telling me she would. 3. She didn't sing just like you said.

Is this sentence something you saw or did you create it yourself? If the sentence(s) come from a single source please tell us where.

Is there a question here? Because I can't see a question mark.

You've given four sentences but only three interpretations, so it's hard to see how you are matching them all. Also, what's the question?

The OP is asking which of the four means the same as (1), which means the same as (2), and which means the same as (3).

(a) is ambiguous, (b) means (3), (c) and (d) probably mean (2). Another possible meaning for (a) is "She didn't sing in the way that you taught/advised her to do".

@KateBunting - "She didn't sing in the way that you taught/advised her to do" - a music teacher's worst nightmare!

Thank you all very much. The question mark is at the end of sentence '3'. It should have been on a separate line. I didn't edit the post fearing that I'd be accused of adding the question mark. The sentences are mine, but I believe they are run-of-the-mill sentences that could be heard in everyday conversations. There are three possible meanings and four sentences. I don't think that is a problem, really. Kate Bunting has provided a perfect answer to my question. A special thanks to her. She also found a meaning that I hadn't thought of, making (a) even more ambiguous!

Gomandeng, you have said it yourself! They are sentences which you might hear in conversations! Not isolated utterances. Conversations about something and in which there were preceding and following utterances., providing context.

Thank you Micheal. Gomandeng? I don't understand that. Maybe you're confusing me with someone else. Anyway, you are correct, but I just wanted to know which sentence to use in which context and when to use the comma. I forgot to thank Seewjooheng for clarifying my question.

Without context, words don't mean much. The real world always provides context, which would usually  resolve any ambiguities of the type being presented here. Speculating what the words might mean without context is just pointless.

Thank you FumbleFingers. I am trying to learn to use the sentences correctly. If I put in the comma when I am not supposed to put it in, then I'd be making a mistake. I am trying to match each sentence to its possible meanings so that I know what sentence to use for my intended meaning. I am going the other way. I am not worried about misunderstanding these sentences, but about misusing them.

With or without the comma makes not the slightest difference to the meaning of "She didn't sing as you said."  And... if you want to improve your English and you realize something is ambiguous, then clarify. It is not a failing to add a few extra words when called for; communication tends to breakdown when meaning  is unclear.

Thank you very much, Mari-Lou. Got it. I think I see what the problem with my question was. I will try to clarify my meaning from now on. I will try to create contexts for my sentences to see if they work in those contexts.

Azz, I apologise for accidentally calling you 'Gomandeng'.

Thank you Michael. No problem at all. It happens.

First: as other comments have pointed out, ambiguity is usually created by lack of context, and is best solved by adding context. (See my demonstration at this question.)
But while punctuation and word choice alone aren't always enough to make meaning clear, in these examples the commas can eliminate some meanings. "As" is a very flexible word that can be used in many ways. In "She sang as you said," it can either mean "she sang in the manner that you said she did" or "she sang, and I am confirming that you said she sang." Again, we don't have to worry about this ambiguity because context would solve it. But adding a comma after sang doesn't work for the first meaning.
Adding the comma makes the words that follow into their own clause and separates them from the words before. Consider an even simpler sentence:

I look like you.

The most likely meaning here is "my appearance is the same as yours." "I" is the subject and "look" is the verb. As our brain notices more words coming, we think "Oh, this is the transitive, linking-verb meaning of 'look,' and what follows must describe my appearance!"
But picture this: Two people are using binoculars. "Look!" says one. "I look, like you" says the other.* The comma (or, spoken, the pause and the change it would have on intonation) change our understanding of "look." It separates the remaining words from it; "Oh," we think, "that's a new phrase and this one is done. This must be the intransitive meaning of 'look,' to observe."
Please don't take away from this simplified example the notion that punctuation alone creates meaning or resolves ambiguity. The guy with the binoculars could probably say it the wrong way, with no pause, and still be understood just because "my appearance is the same as you" makes no sense in that context. But the moral is that punctuation can support contextual meaning, and it does make a difference to how we group the words in our mind, and that makes a difference to how they work together.

* Bear with me. This sentence is awkward and unlikely for someone to say; I'm  something like "I'm looking, just like you" would be more likely. Perhaps a toddler would say this simpler version. But I'm straining an artificial scenario to show how the comma works.

Yeah so this is the kind of test question I find mildly annoying because it sets up as rules things that are only correlations. In other words, any of those sentences could mean several of those things and the commas don't entirely raise the ambiguity, they just reduce it a bit. They still reduce it enough that I think we can identify what the testmaker intended as correct answers:
a) She didn't sing as you said
b) She didn't sing, as you said
c) She didn't sing as you said she did
d) She didn't sing, as you said she did
On first blush "a" could mean anything but the "straightest" parsing of [She [didn't [sing [as you said]]] translates to 1: "She sang but not in the manner you said she sang".
This is strengthened when we see "b", where the comma groups "she didn't sing" and so suggests either 2: "She didn't sing even though you said she did" or 3: "You said she didn't sing and it's true she didn't", which confirms "a" is meant to be "1". Of the two, "3" is the straightest parsing ("like you said = you said 'she didn't sing'"), which is again confirmed when...
...c and d basically work the same way but adding "she did" to "as you said" pretty much excludes the "you said she didn't sing" option (otherwise you'd say "as you said she wouldn't"; contrary to what I said before coming to my senses and editing, this is actually hard to wiggle out of). So "c" would mean 1: She sang but not in the manner you said and "d" would mean 2: "She didn't sing even though you said she did".
